# Custom validation for field form?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using below codes in Bartik theme.

I need to make: Value cannot be `4` in integer `field_total`

But dont know why not working.

```
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'bartik_form_validate';
}
function bartik_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['field_total'] == '4') {
    form_set_error('title', 'Total cannot be "4"');
  }
}
```

New added: clearing cache giving error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: field_total in bartik_form_validate() (line 161 of /var/www/dru7/themes/bartik/template.php).
```

Comment: Why not create a custom module and put all your custom codes there instead of using theme?

Comment: clear your cache

Comment: @saadlulu, This for learning purposes.

Comment: @neok, clearing cache giving error mentioned above

Comment: That is saying there is no value field_total, you need ensure that the form_state actually contains that value as field_total because it may not actually be named that

Comment: if you have `Devel` module installed just - `dpm($form_state['values'])` or you can use `print_r`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$form_state['values']['field_total']` does not exist.

First make sure that you have a field value called field_total.

Second try this code once you make sure you do `$form_state['field_total']['#value']` to get the value of the field.

Comment: Of course I have field `field_total`

Comment: Changing the code still giving an error. Changing field name also not helps

Comment: try using $form instead of $form_state. like this. $form['field_total']['#value']. and show us the error you got.

Comment: Use `$form['field_total']['#value']` can stop the error, but it not works too.

Comment: var_dump($form['field_total']['#value']);exit(); on the first line of your function, copy and paste the result and show us. please!